# Can't add JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

I can't add JTable element to my code. 
If i'm adding it like Drag and Drop it shows me nothing. I tried to add it from java code and i have no result! How to do that i will have a table with all my columns placed in width of my frame?
Here is my Frame

```
   package pack.frames; 

import java.awt.BorderLayout; 
import java.awt.EventQueue; 
import java.awt.Window; 

import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JPanel; 
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder; 
import javax.swing.JMenuBar; 
import javax.swing.JMenu; 
import javax.swing.JTable; 
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel; 
import javax.swing.JScrollPane; 

public class ResutlTable extends JFrame { 

private JPanel contentPane; 


/** 
* Launch the application. 
*/ 
public static void main(String[] args) { 
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
public void run() { 
try { 
ResutlTable frame = new ResutlTable(); 
frame.setVisible(true); 

} catch (Exception e) { 
e.printStackTrace(); 
} 
} 
}); 
} 

/** 
* Create the frame. 
*/ 

String columns[] = {"Оборудование основного производства","Оборудование дополнительного производства","Заработная плата", 
"Прогнозное значение потребительского спроса", "Утилизация отходов", "Распределение квалификации рабочей силы основного производства", 
"Распределение квалификации рабочей силы дополнительного производства", "Метод вывода", "Прибыль предприятия"}; 
Object data[][] = { 
{"0","Tom",new Integer(20),"Male"}, 
{"1","Tina", new Integer(18), "Female"}, 
{"2","Raj",new Integer(19),"Male"}}; 

public ResutlTable() { 
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
setBounds(100, 100, 645, 303); 
setTitle("Система анализа и прогноза функционирования предприятием"); 
contentPane = new JPanel(); 
contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)); 
setContentPane(contentPane); 
contentPane.setLayout(null); 

JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar(); 
menuBar.setBounds(0, 0, 629, 21); 
contentPane.add(menuBar); 

JMenu menu = new JMenu("\u0424\u0430\u0439\u043B"); 
menuBar.add(menu); 

JMenu menu_1 = new JMenu("\u0421\u043F\u0440\u0430\u0432\u043A\u0430"); 
menuBar.add(menu_1); 
JTable table = new JTable(null, columns); 
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table); 
contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
contentPane.setSize(300, 150); 
contentPane.setVisible(true); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Answer (score 1):

```
contentPane.setLayout(null);
```

Don't use a null layout!!!

```
contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

How do you expect the above statement to work? If you want to use a BorderLayout on your panel then you need to set the layout to BorderLayout. The program can't read your mind.

Look at the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for working examples. The tutorials will show you how to better structure your code.